# Asp.NET Core MVC Hangfire Reccuring Job

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

I am trying to use Hangfire in Asp.NET Core MVC web API application. When it runs it throws an System.InvalidOperationException for every reccuring job (I have 3 of them).

Here is how I configured hangfire:

```
private void ConfigureHangfireServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    string connectionString = Repository.Constans.Connection.DbConnectionString;
    services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(connectionString));

    services.AddSingleton(new BackgroundWorkers.ChronJobs());
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
}

private void ConfigureHangFire(IApplicationBuilder app)
{                   
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(Repository.Constans.Connection.DbConnectionString);
```

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new BackgroundWorkers.ContainerJobActivator(serviceProvider));

```
    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/admin/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
    {
        Authorization = new[] { new SecurityHelpers.AdminAuthorization.HangFireAuthorizationFilter()} });

    app.UseHangfireServer();

    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<BackgroundWorkers.ChronJobs>("FinishedEvents", x => x.FinishedEvents(), Cron.Daily(0, 10));
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<BackgroundWorkers.ChronJobs>("IncreaseStock", x => x.IncreaseStock(), Cron.Daily(1,10));
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<BackgroundWorkers.ChronJobs>("TakeWalletAndDonate", x => x.CollectForCharity(), Cron.Daily(2,10));
```

}

The error what I am getting:

System.InvalidOperationException

> No service for type 'BackgroundWorkers.ChronJobs' has been registered.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type
>   'BackgroundWorkers.ChronJobs' has been registered.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext
>   context)    at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0()
>   at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter
>   filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)    at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 filters)    at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
>   at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context,
>   IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)

My ChronJob class:

```
        [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
        public  partial class ChronJobs
        {
            private  readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

            private  readonly IProfileRepository _profileRepository;
            private readonly IEventRepository _eventRepository;
            private readonly IGiftRepository _giftRepository;
            private readonly IShippingAddressRepository _shippingAdressRepository;
            private readonly IChipInRepository _chipInRepository;
            private readonly IPartnersGiftStockRepository _partnersGiftStockRepository;
            private readonly ICharityRepository _charityRepository;

            private readonly ICollectedGiftService _collectedGiftService;

    public ChronJobs(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
                     IProfileRepository profileRepository,
                     IEventRepository eventRepository,
                     IGiftRepository giftRepository,
                     IShippingAddressRepository shippingAdressRepository,
                     IChipInRepository chipInRepository,
                     IPartnersGiftStockRepository partnersGiftStockRepository,
                     ICharityRepository charityRepository,
                     ICollectedGiftService ollectedGiftService)
            {
                _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;

                _profileRepository = profileRepository;
                _eventRepository = eventRepository;
                _giftRepository = giftRepository;
                _shippingAdressRepository = shippingAdressRepository;
                _chipInRepository = chipInRepository;
                _partnersGiftStockRepository = partnersGiftStockRepository;
                _charityRepository = charityRepository;

               _collectedGiftService = collectedGiftService;
            }

            public ChronJobs
            (
                IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,

                IProfileRepository profileRepository,
                IEventRepository eventRepository,
                IGiftRepository giftRepository,
                IShippingAddressRepository shippingAdressRepository,
                IChipInRepository chipInRepository,
                IPartnersGiftStockRepository partnersGiftStockRepository,
                 ICharityRepository charityRepository,

                ICollectedGiftService collectedGiftService
            )
            {
                _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;

                _profileRepository = profileRepository;
                _eventRepository = eventRepository;
                _giftRepository = giftRepository;
                _shippingAdressRepository = shippingAdressRepository;
                _chipInRepository = chipInRepository;
                _partnersGiftStockRepository = partnersGiftStockRepository;
                _charityRepository = charityRepository;

               _collectedGiftService = collectedGiftService;
            }

            public void FinishedEvents()
            {
                //do logic here
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it important that I call my DI before or after I configure Hangfire? In my code now I nocfigure Asp.NET Core MVC's DI after configuring Hangfire?

Please help, what I missed, or of u need any more of my code.
thnx

Comment: Did you register the dependencies those required for `ChronJobs` class in `ConfigureServices` method ?

Comment: Yes I did, but I forgot to add service for my ChronJobs class. Edited my post, and it stil not works.

Tried this one two:
http://nance.io/dotnet/core/async/2016/08/19/long-running-tasks-in-dotnet-core-with-hangfire.html

Comment: Not works still, still same error!